# Unable to connect Point-to-point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) VPN in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, 17.10

How to connect VPN using PPTP in Ubuntu 17.10?

I have provided the Options:

[image: screenshot]

**System Error Log**:

> Nov 15 20:09:25 ST21IND1042 NetworkManager[13773]:  
>   [1510756765.9541] audit: op="connection-activate"
>   uuid="85634108-6d10-4a5c-a0be-acc75f6c9c16" name="COMPANY" pid=15146
>   uid=1000 result="success"
>  Nov 15 20:09:25 ST21IND1042
>   NetworkManager[13773]:   [1510756765.9599]
>   vpn-connection[0x5598beb502c0,85634108-6d10-4a5c-a0be-acc75f6c9c16,"COMPANY",0]:
>   Started the VPN service, PID 17223
>  Nov 15 20:09:25 ST21IND1042
>   NetworkManager[13773]:   [1510756765.9709]
>   vpn-connection[0x5598beb502c0,85634108-6d10-4a5c-a0be-acc75f6c9c16,"COMPANY",0]:
>   Saw the service appear; activating connection
>  Nov 15 20:09:25
>   ST21IND1042 gnome-shell[1388]: **Invalid VPN service type (cannot find
>   authentication binary)**
>  Nov 15 20:09:26 ST21IND1042
>   gnome-shell[1388]: **Invalid VPN service type (cannot find
>   authentication binary)**
>  Nov 15 20:09:26 ST21IND1042
>   NetworkManager[13773]:  [1510756766.0027]
>   vpn-connection[0x5598beb502c0,85634108-6d10-4a5c-a0be-acc75f6c9c16,"COMPANY",0]:
>   **Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request**.
>  Nov 15 20:09:26 ST21IND1042 NetworkManager[13773]:
>     [1510756766.0148]
>   vpn-connection[0x5598beb502c0,85634108-6d10-4a5c-a0be-acc75f6c9c16,"COMPANY",0]:
>   **VPN plugin: state changed: stopped** (6)

Please let me know, if anything i have missed it.

Comment: Do you have the `network-manager-pptp-gnome` package installed?

Comment: Yes. I have installed that package but no luck

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve the same issue like this:

$ ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/

I compared my VPN configurations between my Ubuntu 17.10 and another machine with a different Linux (where the VPN did work) and changed the 17.10 configuration accordingly.

"[vpn]
password-flags=" was set to "1", I changed it to "0"

"[vpn-secrets]
password=" was completely missing, so I just added it after the "[vpn]"-section and filled out my password before saving the configuration.

Then I restarted the network manager:
$ sudo service network-manager restart

That's it.

Comment: Please use code markup, the `{}`on top of the editor.  But I don't think your settings will solve OPs issue, which seems that network manager is unable to find a binary.

Answer (score 2):

I am also having this problem, and was able to workaround by saving the username \ password in the VPN config.  It seems that the real issue is the inability to bring up the password prompt, not the PPTP module itself.

This Arch thread lead me to the answer.  Looks like some additional work with fixing symlinks is needed if you want the password prompt back, assuming this is pretty much the same problem.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=153763

Comment: I've been experiencing a similar issue. Has anyone filed this under a bug on launchpad?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 17.10 I managed to make it work editing the file whose name is the same as the VPN connection's name in directory `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, where I changed the value of `password-flags` to 2, and after `user` I added a field `password` with my password.